# Vaadin addSucceededListener

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have an upload button in Vaadin 8 with an addSucceededListener listener on it- about which i don't know many things..and i couldn't find too much info for this type of listener.
When i click that button i want to fire up a confirmation window - which I instantiate with `ConfirmButton cd = new ConfirmButton("Confirmare");` and i open the modal pop-up with `cd.openInModalPopup();`.

My issue here is that the pop-up -> `cd.openInModalPopup();` shows up only after the "Choose a file" window is open and i must select a file.
My question is how can I show the confirmation first, and only if the uer confirms, open the "Choose a file" window.

Adding the code below:

```
 <vaadin-upload button-caption="Incarc INDICATORI " _id="cmdIncarcRaportInd" :right></vaadin-upload>
```

```
public Upload getCmdIncarcRaportInd() {
        return cmdIncarcRaportInd;
    }
```

```
getCmdIncarcRaportInd().addSucceededListener(event -> {
                    
                    int NR_Raport=0;
                    String WBL ="";
                    WBL = getCheBL().getValue()?"B":"I";
                    
                    if(raport!=null) NR_Raport=Numeric.getValInt(raport.get("Nr. Raport"));
                    
                    if (NR_Raport==0) {
                        Notification notif = new Notification("Atentie",
                                "NR Raport incorect",
                                        Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                notif.setDelayMsec(-1);
                                notif.show(Page.getCurrent());
                                return;
                    }
                    
                    int NR_RaportW = NR_Raport;

                    if(WBL.equals("B")) {
                        NR_RaportW=99;
                        
                        ConfirmButton cd = new ConfirmButton("Confirmare");
                        cd.misWinTitle = "Atentie MIS";
                        cd.misWinText = "Incarcati valori Base Line ? Daca exista deja, cele vechi se vor rescrie cu valorile noi. CONFIRMATI BASE LINE (DA / NU) ?";
                        cd.misButOK = "DA";
                        cd.misButCancel = "NU";
                        cd.setOkAction(()->{
                            
                            String raspuns="ok";
                            if(!receiver.getFile().getName().split("_")[0].equals(proiect.get("Prj cod"))) {
                                Notification notif = new Notification("Atentie", "Cod Proiect Incorect",
                                                Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                        notif.setDelayMsec(-1);
                                        notif.show(Page.getCurrent());
                                        return;
                            }
                            try {
                                raspuns = Utility.getSomeData(receiver.getFile(), proiect, 99, themeDisplay);
                            } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
                                raspuns=e.getMessage();
                            }
                            Notification notificare = new Notification("Atentie - Incarcare Base Line Indicatori",
                                    raspuns,
                                    Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            notificare.setDelayMsec(-1);
                            notificare.show(Page.getCurrent());
                            incarcGrdIndicatori(prj_cod);
                            
                            receiver.uploadFinished(event);
                        });
                        cd.setCancelAction(()->{
                            
                        });             
                        
                        cd.openInModalPopup();
                    } else { 
                        String raspuns="ok";
                                            
    
                        if(!receiver.getFile().getName().split("_")[0].equals(proiect.get("Prj cod"))) {
                            Notification notif = new Notification("Atentie", "Cod Proiect Incorect",
                                            Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                    notif.setDelayMsec(-1);
                                    notif.show(Page.getCurrent());
                                    return;
                        }
                        try {
                            raspuns = Utility.DoSomeStuff(receiver.getFile(), proiect, NR_RaportW, themeDisplay);
                        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
                            raspuns=e.getMessage();
                        }
                        Notification notificare = new Notification("Atentie - Incarcare Rap Indicatori",
                                raspuns,
                                Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        notificare.setDelayMsec(-1);
                        notificare.show(Page.getCurrent());
                        
                        incarcGrdIndicatori(prj_cod);
                        
                        receiver.uploadFinished(event);
                    }
                    
            
                    
                    
                    
                });
        
//);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a normal Button which the users clicks, and then show the Upload Button only when your conditions are meet?

Comment: if i use a normal button with a normal clickListener am not sure how to trigger the window that asks for the file

Comment: The tricky thing to remember with any upload and download event forwarding is that it all has to happen within the same server-client roundtrip, otherwise the browser's security measures block it. So in practice you want the confirmation dialog's 'Ok' button to actually be an upload button, or you have to do the event forwarding on the client-side. Anything that happens within a click listener on the server-side is too late.

Comment: As an additional point, for most Vaadin 8 uploading needs the EasyUploads add-on gives you a leg up and easier configuration options than the default Upload component. https://vaadin.com/directory/component/easyuploads

Comment: @AnnaKoskinen thank you for your info. from what i understand that is a simple button? from what i see there is a ```receiver``` that should do the job? 
do i have to do the event forwarding even if the components are full server-side? this project is done only with server-side components.

Comment: All Vaadin 8 components have both server- and client-side implementations, it's just that for most things you only need to bother with the server-side. But for this particular need the upload must be triggered from the client-side before the event ever reaches the server-side, because it would be a huge security issue if your server could manipulate the end-user's local files. That kind of thing can only be done if the end-user requests it directly, so it has to be an effectively immediate reaction to their button click or similar action.

Comment: To clarify further -- when you add a Vaadin 8 server-side component, it adds the client-side component automatically as well. The client-side component is what you actually see when you look at your application, but you can control its contents via the server-side API.